# Keycloak testSMTPConnection results in 500 Internal Error

Tags: java, smtp, keycloak

I have an endpoint that uses the keycloak java admin client to test the SMTP connection

```
@SneakyThrows
@Override
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('" + WRITE_SMTP_CONFIGURATION + "')")
public void testSMTPConfiguration(@RequestBody Map<String, String> smtpConfigurationModel) {
    
    var response = realmService.realm(TenantContext.getTenantId()).testSMTPConnection(smtpConfigurationModel);
    log.info("Test SMTP email status {}", response.getStatus());
}
```

`realmService.realm(TenantContext.getTenantId())` this just returns the `RealmResource` on which I am calling the `testSMTPConnection` method on.

This will always result in a `500 Internal Server error`.

However, if I'm going in keycloak and using the **Test Connection** button from the UI it successfully sends the email to my gmail account. I am using the same configuration both on the endpoint and on the realm.

```
Server: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587
Start TLS: true
SSL: false
Auth: true
Email/password
```

Any idea why the method does not work but the button in Keycloak realm settings does?